# Pandas using iloc, apply and lambda with df column as part of condition

Tags: pandas, lambda, conditional-statements, apply

So i have that kind of code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

myData = {'Price': [30000, 199, 30000, 199, 199],
          'Length': [7, 7, 7, 7, 6]
          }

df = pd.DataFrame(myData, columns=['Price', 'Length'])

print(df)

df.iloc[:, np.r_[0]] = df.iloc[:, np.r_[0]].apply(lambda x: [y if y >= 30000 else round(y / 2, 0) for y in x])

print(df)
```

What it does is, it takes value from column "Price" and if its equal or above 30 000 then it doesnt change the value otherwise it divides it by 2 and rounds to full numbers.
This on works great, but problem I do have is how to change this code to divide it by value in column "Length" instead ???

I need to use iloc since i dont know names of the columns (they may change but their position wont) and I would like to have it solved using apply and lambda.

Other question is how to use same thing but for example i want to divide two columns (lets say "Price" and "Age" by values in column "Length").

Thanks for any help on this issue.

**EDIT:**

Based on answer below from jezrael i managed to solve my second question by using loop:

```
import pandas as pd

import numpy as np

myData = {'Price': [30000, 199, 30000, 199, 199],
          'Age': [7, 14, 21, 28, 30000],
          'Length': [7, 7, 7, 7, 7]
          }

df = pd.DataFrame(myData, columns=['Price', 'Age', 'Length'])

for column in df.columns[np.r_[0, 1]]:
    df[column] = np.where(df[column] >= 30000, df[column], (df[column] / df.iloc[:, 2]).round())
    print(df[column])

print(df)
```

I wonder if it can be done without using loops though ???

Comment: you can use `column_name = df.columns[0]` to get the column name(s)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) by condition, here `apply` is not recommended, because slow:

```
df.iloc[:, 0] = np.where(df.iloc[:, 0] >= 30000, 
                         df.iloc[:, 0], 
                         (df.iloc[:, 0] / df.iloc[:, 1]).round())
print(df)
     Price  Length
0  30000.0       7
1     28.0       7
2  30000.0       7
3     28.0       7
4     33.0       6
```

EDIT:

For working with multiple columns use [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) and divide values by [`DataFrame.div`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.div.html) with `axis=0`:

```
df.iloc[:, [0, 1]] = np.where(df.iloc[:, [0, 1]] >= 30000,
                              df.iloc[:, [0, 1]], 
                              df.iloc[:, [0, 1]].div(df.iloc[:, 2], axis=0).round())
print (df)
     Price      Age  Length
0  30000.0      1.0       7
1     28.0      2.0       7
2  30000.0      3.0       7
3     28.0      4.0       7
4     28.0  30000.0       7
```

Comment: Can this be also used to divide two columns at same time by third column ? Or do I have to use that scheme for each column individualy ?

Comment: @JerryC - Not sure if understand, why are used here loops? Is possible edit question with new problem?

Comment: Sorry i am working on editing that and there was wrong code. This is what I have managed to answer my question (will paste it below because i cant edit it in comment to look good :( ). I just wonder if it can be done without loops ???

Comment: @JerryC - Understand, give me a sec.

Comment: @jezrrael - Edited main post

Answer (score 2):

One way is to find all indexes where the column is less than 30000 using `.loc` and `.iloc`. With this filter apply the division to the desired data

```
mask = df.loc[df.iloc[:,0] < 30000].index
df.iloc[mask, 0] = (df.iloc[mask, 0] / df.iloc[mask, 1]).round()

#output
    Price   Length
0   30000.0 7
1   28.0    7
2   30000.0 7
3   28.0    7
4   33.0    6
```